# Methods don't show in Swagger UI (w/ Swashbuckle) but no error message

Tags: c#, swagger, swashbuckle

I'm writing an api with Swashbuckle, but running into issues.  I have three Get methods in my AController:

```
[ResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<A>))]
public IHttpActionResult Get(int bId);

[ResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<A>))]
public IHttpActionResult Get(IList<int> cIds);

[ResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<A>))]
public IHttpActionResult Get(int bId, IList<int> cIds);
```

I would expect either an error about overloading endpoints or for it to work with a single get method with two optional parameters, covering all cases.  Instead, I'm only getting the second method to show, which seems arbitrary.

I'm wondering, is there any way to get all three to work, and also, is there a reason beyond chance that the second method is shown in the UI? Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a more complete sample of your interface and your class implementation? I'm not familiar with either `Swagger` or `Swashbuckle`, but I am guessing your issues aren't in what you have posted here. Or possibly, you haven't got a good rebuild. Try completely cleaning your solution... go into the folder and manually delete all `bin` and `obj` folders in each project of your solution. Then do a new build.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations, I've ruled out the rebuilding possibility, it didn't help.  I'm about to edit to add more detail, but I know Swagger is notoriously finicky about the design of apis. For example, a common issue people have, which I would have expected to have, is this: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/issues/142

Comment: Can you reach all three methods?  I'm guessing only one method has its routes set up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question, you are able to get all three GET methods to work by defining different endpoints for them. For each GET method, add the following attribute: [HttpGet("the_end_point_you_want")].

ie)

```
[HttpGet("/GetbID/{bId})")
[ResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<A>))]
public IHttpActionResult Get(int bId)

[HttpGet("/GetListcId")]
[ResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<A>))]
public IHttpActionResult Get(IList<int> cIds)
```

For your second question, I am unsure as to why the second GET is chosen but my guess would be how SwashBuckle retrieves each GET method.

Hope this helps